# Breakfast burritos from 16 egg casserole, how to cook everything uniformly?

Tags: baking, eggs, freezing, cooking-time, casserole

I am baking a 16 egg casserole that will be used for breakfast burritos and so I want the egg mixture to be cooked uniformly through. Once the breakfast burritos are made I will freeze them all. **What is the best way to cook the egg casserole uniformly?**

- over the stove with a large skillet? large wok over stove?
- baking with a casserole dish or metal skillet in oven? with lid or without lid? what temperature time (i.e. hot 350+ F and shorter time or cooler 250-300 F and longer) and how long?
- (maybe you have another way that is not stove+skillet nor baking.)

I chose to go with baking because I think such a large volume of eggs is too difficult[1] to cook over a stove in a skillet/wok.

---

[1]
I say difficult because when I cook a 10-11 egg mixture over a stove with a 10 inch skillet the cooking requires stirring vigorously the entire egg mixture throughout the entire cooking process and the total time is something like 5-10 minutes plus or minus (I haven't measured how long I just look at the egg consistency). So after half way through finishing stirring you start to get tired and sometimes you get parts that get harder if you slack in your stirring. And so I can't imagine doing the same thing with 16 eggs I don't think I would have the stamina to cook stirring that long and I would be concerned about food safety with everything cooking through.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve? Why can't you make 1 or 2 eggs worth of burritos quickly, then set them aside and make another 1 or 2 eggs worth, and so on, until in one morning you have stocked your freezer with egg burritos? Why do all 16 need to cook in a single swoop - which as you've mentioned is very difficult? Until you explain why they have to all cook at once I doubt you will get very good advice.

Comment: Just for clarification for those not so familiar with the recipe: You are basically making a 16-eggs portion of scrambeled eggs? Or are you aiming for something entirely different?

Comment: @Stephie the egg mixture has potatoes, green peppers, onions, corn, black beans. But more or less the goal is scrambled eggs with all of the above ingredients.

Comment: @KateGregory the egg mixture has lots of ingredients and so I thought doing all at once would be faster and easier.

Answer (score 1):

Baked, covered, at low heat :

- ovens self-regulate, so you're going to get a more consistent result each time than doing it on the stovetop.
- covering will minimize evaporation, which will cool the top more.
- low heat will minimize problems with the edges cooking before the middle ... but eggs also have this strange thing where it's more difficult to over cook them at low heat ... and it's not just an issue of carry-over cooking (which lower heat will help to minimize, too).

As for shape of the vessel, I'd go with a rectangular baking dish -- because then I could more easily portion out 16 equal sized servings than from a round or oblong vessel.